# Use sockets to connect and download webpage of hidden service

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, proxy, tor

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, "127.0.0.1", 9150, True)
socket = socks.socksocket()
socket.connect(('onionlink.onion', 80))
message = 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
socket.sendall(str.encode(message))
reply = socket.recv(4069)
print (reply)
```

This code works but the response is empty... The terminal prints this:

```
b''
```

Is there something wrong? How can I print the source of the hidden service?

Comment: "Website addresses that end in “.onion” aren’t like normal domain names, and you can’t access them with a normal web browser. Addresses that end with “.onion” point to Tor hidden services on the “deep web”." Friom here: https://www.howtogeek.com/272049/how-to-access-.onion-sites-also-known-as-tor-hidden-services/

Comment: I am under tor, in fact I set the traffic under it here: socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, "127.0.0.1", 9150, True)

Comment: The connection is successfull, but I don't understand why the source I get is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was needed to add `http://` to `message = 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'`

So now is: message = 'GET http://onionlink.onion HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'